# view controller state after mpmovieplayercontroller full screen mode iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, mpmovieplayercontroller

i have taken a .Storyboard Project and for video playing i am using separate .XIB file.
When i add a view player xib on my storyboard content view, it played video well

But, when i enter to fullscreen mode and come back, content of the previous view is getting clear/nil.

Can anybody help!

Thanks

Comment: post your relevant code

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are loosing strong references to you view controller contents . make them strong to keep the reference. 
example-

```
property(nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;// for example only
```

by this you will not loose this object(imageView) until the controller is present in memory.

Comment: Thanks @pawan for your comment, but i have already made it (nonatomic, strong)

Comment: in that case , please paste you code here, that will help in solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know without your code. so what you have mistaken. here is my guessing answer for you

**fullscreen**

A Boolean that indicates whether the movie player is in full-screen mode.

**@property (nonatomic, getter=isFullscreen) BOOL fullscreen**

**Discussion**

The default value of this property is NO. Changing the value of this property causes the movie player to enter or exit full-screen mode immediately. If you want to animate the transition to full-screen mode, use the setFullscreen:animated: method instead.

Whenever the movie player enters or exits full-screen mode, it posts appropriate notifications to reflect the change. For example, upon entering full-screen mode, it posts **`MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification`** and **`MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification`** notifications. Upon exiting from full-screen mode, it posts **`MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification`** and **`MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification`** notifications.

The value of this property may also change as a result of the user interacting with the movie player controls.

reference by [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMoviePlayerController/fullscreen)